# Generate array of students (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I need to generate Array of students with those properties:
Name, Surname, Speciality, Course, Groupe.

I write class Student and try to create 5 students

Here is code

```
public class Student {
String Name;
String Surname;
String Course;
String Groupe;
String Speciality;


Student student = new Student();

public Student getStudent1() {
    student.Name = "Anastasia";
    student.Surname = "Enina";
    student.Speciality = "Programmer";
    student.Course = "4";
    student.Groupe = "1B";
    return student;
}

public Student getStudent2(){
    student.Name = "Anastasia";
    student.Surname = "Enina";
    student.Speciality = "Programmer";
    student.Course = "4";
    student.Groupe = "1B";
    return student;
}
public Student getStudent3(){
    student.Name = "Eugene";
    student.Surname = "Sukhomlyn";
    student.Speciality = "Economist";
    student.Course = "3";
    student.Groupe = "2B";
    return student;
}
public Student getStudent4(){
    student.Name = "Victor";
    student.Surname = "Sologub";
    student.Speciality = "Designer";
    student.Course = "5";
    student.Groupe = "2A";
    return student;
}
public Student getStudent5(){
    student.Name = "Serhiy";
    student.Surname = "Koshelnick";
    student.Speciality = "Audit";
    student.Course = "1";
    student.Groupe = "4C";
    return student;
}
```

}

In main I need to add those students to Array

So I tried this code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Student> mStudents = new ArrayList<>();

    mStudents.add(student);
}
```

but I have error `cannot resolve symbol student`

How I need to write code correctly?

Comment: there is no `student` variable in main, so where is it coming from? is it a field?

Comment: @Ramanlfc: line 9 :D

Comment: it need to come from student class@Ramanlfc

Comment: is the `main` defined inside `Student`?

Comment: Nope Student is a different class@Ramanlfc

Comment: then you need to define the student variable inside the main method or the class which contains main method, in that case it should be static

Comment: Having a `Student student = new Student();` inside every `Student` is probably not going to end well for your java process.

Comment: Scrap all that code as it's broken and start over. You shouldn't be hard-coding creation of individual students within the Student class. Instead it should be created to be used by other classes to create individual Student objects.

Comment: the task is to create array of students not `ArrayList`. as @HovercraftFullOfEels mentioned scrap this code ,in fact read a bit about arrays and classes first

Answer (score 0):

You will drop all those functions: `getStudentX()` - instead you write a constructor, that takes an argument for each property.

That constructor will look something like this:

```
public Student(String name, String ...) {
    this.name = name;
    ...
}
```

You also drop that `Student student;` line.

Then you write:

```
mStudent.add(new Student(arg1, arg2, ....));
```

to create a new `Student` instance that you add to your array.

Comment: But in task I need to creatу class student and generate array with 5 students

Comment: Yeah, the class you have. That are basically your first 6 lines. To this class you need to add a `Constructor` which is used to construct the `instances`. Then in your `main`-function you use that constructor 5 times to create 5 instances that you add to your `mStudent`-array.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your student class with all instance variables, a constructor including all variables, a preferably getters and setters for every variable. Then, from your main (testing class) create and ArrayList and include every student.

```
ArrayList<Student> mStudents = new ArrayList<>();
mStuddents.add(new Student(Anastasia, Enina, Programmer, 4, 1B);
```

Answer (score 0):

The student class should be nothing more than a blueprint. When you create multiple "students", you should do that from main(). Ie,

Student student1 = new Student();

Student student2 = new Student();

...

Student student5 = new Student();

Then to add them to your array, do as you are now, but with the actual student objects:

mStudents.add(student1);

mStudents.add(student2);

...

mStudents.add(student5);

You're going to need to rewrite your Student class, as how you have it now doesn't really make sense.
Look at this link for reference:
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a class called Student. 
Then you will add a constructor to that class in order to be able to instantiate a new Student.

```
public class Student {
 private String name;
 private String surname;
 private String course;
 private String groupe;
 private String speciality;

 public Student(String name,
               String surname,
               String course,
               String groupe,
               String speciality)
 {
     this.name = name;
     this.surname = surname;
     this.course = course;
     this.groupe = groupe;
     this.speciality = speciality;
 }

}
```

Once the constructor is written you will be able to instantiate a new object like this:

```
 Student student1 = new Student("name1", "surname1", "course1", "groupe1", "speciality1");
```

Finnaly, you will be able to create an arraylist of student this way:

```
//instantiation of multiple students
Student student1 = new Student("name1", "surname1", "course1", "groupe1", "speciality1");
//..
Student student5 = new Student("name5", "surname5", "course5", "groupe5", "speciality5");

// Creation of an ArrayList
ArrayList<Student> mStudents = new ArrayList();

// Adding students to the ArrayList
mStudents.add(student1);
//...
mStudents.add(student5);
```

hope this will help you !

Comment: I don't think that the line `package ...` helps. It might be that someone using your answer will add that exact line to each file for years to come :D

Comment: Oups, I didn't notice it ! 
it may be a sneaky way to spread my name over internet ;)
Thank you for your comment, I will correct it :)